# Extracting multiple matches using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm new to regex and cannot seem to figure out how to create an array containing matches like `\nmedia_1.ts`, `\nmedia_2.ts`, etc from the string `s` as shown below.

Any suggestions on how the regex expression can be improved?

```
s = '#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_1.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_2.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_3.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_4.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_5.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_6.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_7.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_8.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_9.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_10.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_11.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_12.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_13.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_14.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_15.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502'
pattern = re.compile('nmedia_(.*?).ts', re.IGNORECASE)
match = pattern.findall(s)
match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend being explicit as possible with your regex statement. So the improvement I'd recommend would be `\d+` to match one or more digits instead of `.*`, zero or more of anything.

Since you're new to regex, using the verbose flag might be of interest to you. (It's also just good for documentation.) Here's a code sample:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

s = r'#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_1.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_2.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_3.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_4.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_5.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_6.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_7.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_8.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_9.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_10.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_11.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_12.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_13.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_14.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_15.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502'
pattern = r"""
\\        # Match literal backslash
nmedia_   # Match the text 'nmedia_'
(         # Begin capturing group 1.
\d+       # Match one or more digits.
)         # End capturing group 1.
\.        # Match a literal dot.
ts        # Match the text 'test'
"""
pattern_match = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
match = pattern_match.findall(s)
print(match)
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```

And here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bG0xP1/1).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the capturing group and you must need to use `\n` newline character not `n` in regex.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\nmedia_.*?\.ts', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
match = pattern.findall(s)
```

If you wnt only the number,

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\nmedia_(.*?)\.ts', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
match = pattern.findall(s)
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\nmedia_(.*?)\.ts', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> s = '#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_1.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_2.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_3.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_4.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_5.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_6.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_7.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_8.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_9.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_10.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_11.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_12.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_13.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.666,\nmedia_14.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502\n#EXTINF:16.667,\nmedia_15.ts?wowzasessionid=184420502'
>>> pattern.findall(s)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\nmedia_.*?\.ts', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
>>> pattern.findall(s)
['\nmedia_1.ts', '\nmedia_2.ts', '\nmedia_3.ts', '\nmedia_4.ts', '\nmedia_5.ts', '\nmedia_6.ts', '\nmedia_7.ts', '\nmedia_8.ts', '\nmedia_9.ts', '\nmedia_10.ts', '\nmedia_11.ts', '\nmedia_12.ts', '\nmedia_13.ts', '\nmedia_14.ts', '\nmedia_15.ts']
>>>
```